# Start script missing error when running npm start, issue persists when changing scripts start value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

Im getting this error

```
npm ERR! missing script: start
```

when I try to run 'npm start' for this new react project I'm working on. I've looked around for a solution and saw some folks found success when they did something like this in their package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
}
```

I attempted replicating the above code but got the same error when I tried to run "npm start". Are there any other steps I can take to fix this error?

Comment: Check you are in the right directory before executing your script.

Comment: `node index.js` doesn't like it would be much use for a React app.

Answer (score 0):

Default scripts for a react project in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```